# DataTables Child Row - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined** when trying to display the child row in my DataTable. I've got the images showing but when I click I get the error.

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

I've reviewed the guide on their site but can't seem to crack it. Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Note - I've renamed fields and the url in the ajax for security purposes. 
Please take a look at my code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "URL Goes here",
    method: "POST",
    data: '{"Id":"' + id + '", "Title": "' + title + '", "Manager": "' + manager + '", "StartDate": "' + startDate + '", "Status": "' + status + '", "Applications": "' + applications + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var table = jQuery('#MyData').DataTable({
            data: data.d,
            retrieve: true,
            responsive: true,
            columns:
                [
                    {
                        "class": 'details-control',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "ID",
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<a target=_blank href="https://www.google.com' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Manager" },
                    { "data": "StartDate" },
                    { "data": "Status" },
                    { "data": "Applications" }
                ],
            order: [[6, "desc"]]
        });
        // Add event listener for opening and closing details
        jQuery('#MyData').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                jQuery('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp(function () {
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                });
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                jQuery('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown;
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });
    }
});

function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return
    '<div class="slider" name>' +
        '<table>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>ID:</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.Id + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Applications:</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.Applications + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>'
}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Responsive extension along with child row functionality. [According to Allan Jardine](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36395/using-responsive-and-another-child-row), creator of jQuery DataTables, it's not possible to use both features since Responsive extension uses child rows API.

See [feature compatibility chart](https://datatables.net/download/compatibility) and see notes for Responsive and child rows functionality.

If you just want to always show certain columns in a child row, you can remove `format()` function, click handler and apply [special class](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes) `none` to `th` element of the column you want to show in a child row.

Also if you want to display child row control on its own column, see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/column-control.html).

Comment: I'm going to amend the data to pull in additional fields from the DB, I've just used existing fields to get it working for now. I essentially copied the example code to do this..so is it incorrect on the DataTables site?

Comment: @TwistedSteel, the official example doesn't use `responsive: true` while you do. I guess these two features are not compatible. See [feature compatibility chart](https://datatables.net/download/compatibility) and see notes for Responsive and child rows functionality.